# Patch: auto answer no

Tags: patch

Suppose patch tell me

`Assume -R? [n]`

in already patched source
Is there a way to say n no automatically?
I can use yes n|patch but i prefer a more clean solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `-f` (`--force`) and `-N` (`--forward`) options, assuming that you use *GNU patch*. They may do what you want or may be insufficient with particular patches. If they are insufficient, you can use the `expect` utility, which can answer depending on the question.